# Related File Permission To Execute The Application

Tags: matlab, file-permissions, user-permissions

I accomplished writing an application code in Matlab. I create a .mat file and save data into it somewhere in the code. I converted it to a standalone application file.(exe) However, I don't want to give permission to the user to see and modify this .mat file because the application uses that file in the next executions. For this reason, I changed the permission settings by right clicking the folder and:

```
properties-Security-Advanced-Changed Permission
```

However, after changing the permission, the code cannot reach that file and fails while executing. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion you are approaching this the wong way. To make that concept working, your application would require higher permissions than the user has, especially the user may not modify permissions. For the majority of self-administrated PCs this is impossible, because the primary user has full administrative rights, allowing to modify folder permissions.

For such cases the typical solution is encryption. Assume everyone can access your files, store only encrypted files to the hard drive.

Comment: However, after encryption, while executing the application, it will ask the user to enter the password. My request is that user should be able to run the file without any problem while he cannot modify that .mat file. To do that, I created a standard user in windows 7 and modified the permissions of it. However, it failed.

Comment: Giving the password to the user would allow the user again to modify the file. Your code has to hold the secret. I recommend to use some obscurification and not store the password directly in a constant variable. Otherwise it might be to simple to read it from the binary.